# insert one row in database and update it in the same action method asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

how can i insert one row in the database and update it in the same action method i write this code but it doesn't updated??

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(reg.users);
                db.Idea.Add(reg.idea);
                db.Students.Add(reg.students[0]);
                db.SaveChanges();

                int max1 = db.Users.Max(p => p.UserId);
            int max22 = db.Idea.Max(d => d.IdeaId);
            int max33 = db.Students.Max(c => c.StudentID);

            var result = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentID == max33);
            result.UserId = max1;
            result.IdeaId = max22;

            db.SaveChanges();
                return View("RegisterLeaderPost");


            }
```

this is student model
i want to update the foreign key 
            public int UserId

```
        public int? IdeaId
```

i don't get any ERROR but the null values dosn't updated

```
 public class StudentsModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name ="ID")]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]//20150090
        public string student_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Skills")]
        public string Skills { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gpa")]
        [Range(1.00, 4.00, ErrorMessage = "It must be in range 0.00 to 4.00 :)")]
        public float Gpa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Leader")]
        public string Leader { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "transcript")]
        public string transcript { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public int UserId;
        public UsersModel Users { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdeaId")]
        public int? IdeaId;
        public IdeaModel Idea { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: which is the object that you want to update result?

Comment: yes, var result

Comment: what error you are getting here?

Comment: no errors but didn't update the foreign key 
result.UserId = max1;result.IdeaId = max22;

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Entity Framework (my mistake I thought you were using the Core version of Entity Framework), if that is correct then I might suggest to do something like this:

```
   db.Update(result);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the reference to that code:

[Modifying data via the DbContext](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data)

Comment: .Update(result)
DBset<studentsModel> doesn't  contain a definition for update

show me this error when i use it

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? Because in my Application I can use something like this:
    dbContext.Company.Update(company);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

Without issues.  Is db a class of the DbContext type?

Comment: version 4.5.2
yes DbContext type

Comment: Can you please copy your DbContext class?

Comment: public DbSet<UsersModel> Users { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS0114 // Member hides inherited member; missing override keyword
        public DbSet<StudentsModel> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdeaModel> Idea { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProfessorsIdeas> ProfessorsIdea { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Once you add an entity to its collection like adding `user` to `Users` it will return an object of this entity and you can use it after `SaveChanges` as it will contain the new IDs.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = db.Users.Add(reg.users);
    var idea = db.Idea.Add(reg.idea);
    var student = db.Students.Add(reg.students[0]);
    db.SaveChanges();

    student.UserId = user.UserId;
    student.IdeaId = idea.IdeaId;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("RegisterLeaderPost");
}
```